# How to filter data from locals based on if else condition terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm, terraform-template-file, hashicorp

**Main.tf**

```
locals {
    location_mapping = [
    {
        "url": "L1.tfe.com"
        "location": "L1"
        "resource_group_name": "R1"
        "name_log_workspace_name": "W1"
    },
    {
        "url": "L2.tfe.com"
        "location": "L2"
        "resource_group_name": "R2"
        "name_log_workspace_name": "W2"
    },
    {
        "url": "L3.tfe.com"
        "location": "L3"
        "resource_group_name": "R3"
        "name_log_workspace_name": "W3"
    }
    ]
}

data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
    # Populate name and resource group based on var.location(L2) condition if location matches in locals
    name                = "W2"
    resource_group_name = "R2"
}
```

I want to populate **name** and **resource_group_nam**e dynamically based on the `location and url` condition in data block from locals.

Example

if I pass `location value L2` and `url value L2.tfe.com` then I will get `name=W2` and `resource_group_name=R2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something as the following should be suited, **assuming** there can be only one match:

```
variable "location" {
  default = "L2"
}

variable "url" {
  default = "L2.tfe.com"
}

locals {
    location_mapping = [
    {
        "url": "L1.tfe.com"
        "location": "L1"
        "resource_group_name": "R1"
        "name_log_workspace_name": "W1"
    },
    {
        "url": "L2.tfe.com"
        "location": "L2"
        "resource_group_name": "R2"
        "name_log_workspace_name": "W2"
    },
    {name_log_workspace_name
        "url": "L3.tfe.com"
        "location": "L3"
        "resource_group_name": "R3"
        "name_log_workspace_name": "W3"
    }
    ]
    
   selected_mapping = lookup({for val in local.location_mapping:
                           0 => val if val.location == var.location  &&
                          val.url == var.url}, 0,
                       {
                            "url": "default"
                            "location": "default_L"
                            "resource_group_name": "default_R"
                            "name_log_workspace_name": "default_W"
                       })
    
}

data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {    
    name                = local.selected_mapping.name_log_workspace_name
    resource_group_name = local.selected_mapping.resource_group_name
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marcin I need to match 2 conditions `location` and `url`

Comment: @NaveenKumar You can just add `and` to the `if`. I updated the answer.

Comment: I need like if condition doesn't match then I need some default value to get I have tried using else but getting error.

Comment: @NaveenKumar I updated the answer yet again. But next time, please provide all these details in the question when you make it.

Comment: @NaveenKumar How did it go?

Comment: working fine but not sure about whats going in `lookup` if you could explain a bit whats 0 in for loop